# Скрытие элемента после щелчка по другому

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как скрыть элемент (`message`) по клике другому элементу (`q-delete-icon`)? В данный момент такой код:

```js
 
$(function() {
    $('.q-delete-icon').click(function(){
        $('.message').click(function(){
            $(this).hide('slow');
        });
    });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='message'> 
    <div class='q-delete-icon' id='2'>close</div>
    От кого:<a href='#'>Ttt</a> | <br />
    2013-07-23 19:31:44<br />
    Сообщение
</div>
```

Comment: Структуру HTML покажите. И при чем тут ajax в тегах? Может быть jQuery?

Comment: Да, jquery. Необходимо чтобы элемент message скрывался именно тот, по которому кликнули на q-delete-icon.
Первый раз все как надо, второй раз уже скрывается message даже если не кликать на q-delete-icon.

HTML: 

<div class='message'> <div class='q-delete-icon' id='2'></div>От кого:<a href='#'>Ttt</a> | <br />2013-07-23 19:31:44<br />Сообщение</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.q-delete-icon').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.message').hide('slow');
});
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/XahXU/